# Google spreadsheet > Get yesterday cost value for each campaign

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet containing my campaigns cost on a daily basis. The day date is in column B, the campaign name in column C, and the daily Cost in column D >> [tab example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqMa9.png)

I try to do 2 things here:

- For each campaign, in column A, make appear the campaign cost of yesterday. I made it through this formula and it works perfectly:

  if(B5=(TODAY()-1),D5,"")

However, applying this formula will make appear the daily cost in cell A only if cell B is = to the yesterday date, and the rest of the cell will remain the empty. So the second thing I would like to do is:

- To make appear yesterday cost for all remaining cells of a same campaign: if yesterday cost of campaign Number1 is 20€, I would like to make appear those 20€ in all other days within the campaign Number1:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Taot8.png)

Do you have an idea of which formula should I use? I have tried many formulas like the max if function, index function including a match and max formula, but couldn't find the right one.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Hi Sami88, welcome to SO. Please take a moment to ensure that your question has 1) a [minimal, viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which in turn contains 2) clearly defined inputs, and 3) clearly defined desired output.

In your case, you have 2), in a way. But it's not clear what you desire. For Google Sheet questions, please include example sheet (unless it's very atomic questions), in addition to parameters that define your input/output data. *Inline* images do help explaining. (inline is better than link) But..

Comment: ..inline image still requires answerers to recreate your sheet and that is not productive use of time.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want to display the last "media cost" occurrence for each category in the "spend yesterday" only prior to the current day. Here's how it can be done.

1 - Make a helper column in Cell E2 with the formula `=IF(B2<TODAY(),COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2),"")`
 and drag it down, you can hide it if you want.

2 - in A1 Past this formula `=IF(B2:B="",,IF(B2<TODAY(),INDEX(SORTN(QUERY(FILTER($B$2:$E,$C$2:$C=C2,$B$2:$B<=TODAY())," Select * where Col4 is not null "),1,,4,0),1,3),""))`
 and drag it down.

note that the highlighted cell with yellow is the current day date, is highlighted automatically using conditional formating. see this image
[image: 1]
you can make a copy of [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F0ac4YitvdU0IUL6i7WcOezlJnUHVBQN1Yye9MP0uJo/edit?usp=sharing) directly.

I hope this answer your question.

Comment: Hi Osm thank you for answering. Following your excel and taking the "Display - Prospecting Audiences" campaign as an example, I would like to make appear this cost "€42.79" in cell A2, A3, A4 (all line having this same campaign in column C), because this was the cost spent yesterday for this campaign. Sorry if I was not clear enough.